# Настройка .htaccess - убрать .html

Tags: .htaccess, веб-программирование, apache2

Ребят, добрый день!

Подскажите, пож-ста, как грамонтно настроить секцию перенаправления файла .htaccess:

- 1) убрать `.html` в строке браузера для всех страниц, например, страница news.html дожна быть в виде `mysite.com/news`
- 2) отображать файл `post-12-01-2015.html` в строке браузера как `mysite.com/posts/2015/01/12`.

Пока имею секцию rewrite в таком виде:

```
# REWRITE ___________________

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite
    RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.mysite.com [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Хостинг - виртуальный.

Редирект должен осуществляться на URL без .html при любых условиях:

Всем неравнодушным большое спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
# Редирект с www на без www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.mysite.com [R=301,L]

# Редирект с post-12-01-2015.html на posts/2015/01/12 от корня
RewriteRule ^post-(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\.html$ /posts/$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L,NC]
# Не только от корня
# RewriteRule post-(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\.html$ posts/$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L,NC]

# Убираем .html во всех случаях
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L,QSA]
```

Флаг `NC` означает нечувствительность к регистру.

Можно проверить [здесь](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Слишком мало информации вы привели. К примеру, при каких условиях должен осуществляться редирект на URL без .html?

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает, ошибка такая: "сервер перенаправляет запрос на этот адрес таким образом, что он никогда не завершится". Перенаправлять не нужно, нужно только отображаться содержимое файла post-12-01-2015.html, а строке браузера было видно posts/2015/01/12.